# the NGINX reverse proxy does not load images

Tags: nginx-reverse-proxy

I have the following nginx.conf, the forwarding also works without errors,

```
#user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
events { worker_connections 1024; }

http {
  server {
        listen 80;
        server_name 192.168.0.87;
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }

    server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name 192.168.0.87;

        ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/Usercerts/usersign.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/Usercerts/usersign.key;

        root /var/www/html;

        location / {
            # Hier kommen deine weiteren Konfigurationen hin
            # z.B. Proxy-Einstellungen oder statische Dateien

            index index.html;
        }

    location ^~ /server1{
      proxy_pass https://192.168.0.181;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
    
    location ^~ /server2{
      proxy_pass https://192.168.0.81;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

   
  }
}
```

but unfortunately the images of the pages called up are not displayed, even an extensive search on the net has not helped me so far.
So my question to you, do you have any other ideas?

Thanks and Regards

Comment: I have the same issue, I hope someone answers something here soon =)